# How to take user selected hotel room and multiply by number of days stayed?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, date

I am able to calculate the difference between the check-in date and check-out date to get the number of days stayed and whether or not the check-out date is before the check-in date.

However, I'm struggling to figure out how to take the user selected room (standard, queen, king, business, or deluxe) and multiple the cost per night of that room by the number of days stayed at the hotel.

I would also like to use the type="date" instead of datepicker if possible.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <script>
  function check() {
   var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById('checkin').value);
   var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById('checkout').value);
   var diff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
   var dayDiff = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));  
  
   if (date1 > date2){ 
    alert("Check-out date must be after check-in date!")
   }
   else {
    calculate();
   } 
  }

</script>
<body>
  <form>
 <fieldset>
   <legend>Reserve Hotel Room</legend>
   Check-In Date:<br>
   <input type="date" id="checkin" name="checkin" required>
   <br><br>
   Check-Out Date:<br>
   <input type="date" id="checkout" name="checkout" required>
   <br><br>
   Room:
   <select id="room" name="room" onchange="report(this.value)">
    <option id="standard" value="50">Standard ($50/night)</option>
    <option id="queen" value="75">Queen ($75/night)</option>
    <option id="king" value="100">King ($100/night)</option>
    <option id="business" value="125">Business ($125/night)</option>
    <option id="deluxe" value="150">Deluxe Suite ($150/night)</option>
   </select>
   <button type="submit" onclick="check()">Submit</button>
   </fieldset>
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Would something like this work?   function calculate();
   if (document.getElementById("standard")
    var report = this.value * 50 * dayDiff;

Comment: Input type "date" is not supported by all browsers in use so not practical. All you need to do is multiply the number of days by the value of the *room* element: `dayDiff * document.getElementById('room').value`. You should probably use *Math.round* rather than *Math.ceil* (check with a range going out of daylight saving)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your Calculate function

```
function calculate(dayDiff) {
    var e = document.getElementById("room");
    var amt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; //gets selected value. As you have set value as price per night. its easier to calculate the total amount.
    return  dayDiff * parseInt(amt);
}
```

UPDATE: to alert the user in a pop-box?

Inside your check function.

```
var totalamount = calculate(dayDiff);
alert(totalamount)
```

Comment: How do I make the return value be alerted to the user in a pop-box?

Comment: @ChaCol calculate function returns the total amount. check i have updated my answer